# php script to save POST to database and send email

Tags: php, mysql, post

Im trying to write a php scrip that will take POSTed variables and save them to a database then send an email with those variables.

Ive put together the below using methods I have used separately before without issue. I've made a mistake somewhere here thoug as I get the following warning on the page: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ws')' at line 16`

I dont understand this warning as there is no ''ws')' at or near line 16.

**What am I not getting here?**

I took out all of the code for saving to the database and the email worked fine but I still cant see whats wrongwith the database code.

```
<?php 

$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$number = $_POST['number'] ;
$ext = $_POST['ext'] ;
$startDay = $_POST['startDay'] ;
$endDay = $_POST['endDay'] ;
$startTime = $_POST['startTime'] ;
$endTime = $_POST['endTime'] ;
$startDay2 = $_POST['startDay2'] ;
$endDay2 = $_POST['endDay2'] ;
$startTime2 = $_POST['startTime2'] ;
$endTime2 = $_POST['endTime2'] ;
$sine = $_POST['sine'] ;
$webmaster_email = "support@website.com";
$hostname = "Sines.db.42.mywebresource.com";
$username = "Sines";
$dbname = "Sines";
$password = "Password!";
$usertable = "contact";



$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO contact (
`email` ,
`number` ,
`ext` ,
`startDay` ,
`endDay` ,
`startTime` ,
`endTime` ,
`startDay2` ,
`endDay2` ,
`startTime2` ,
`endTime2` ,
`sine`
)
VALUES
('$_POST[email]','$_POST[number]','$_POST[ext]','$_POST[startDay]','$_POST[endDay]','$_POST[startTime]','$_POST[endTime]','$_POST[startDay2]','$_POST[endDay2]','$_POST[startTime2]','$_POST[endTime2]'),'$_POST[sine]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "User", ' ' , mysql_insert_id() , ' ' ,"added";
$_SESSION["PRid"] = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_close($con);

/*Below is for sending the email.*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
if ( isInjected($email) ) {
}
else {
       $contents = <<<EOM
Email: $email
Number: $number
Ext: $ext
StartDay: $startDay
EndDay: $endDay
StartTime: $startTime
EndTime: $endTime
StartDay2: $startDay2
EndDay2: $endDay2
StartTime2: $startTime2
EndTime2: $endTime2
Sine: $sine
EOM;

mail( "$webmaster_email", "Contact", $contents);

}

?>
```

My database:

[image]

Comment: Difficult to debug without seeing the actually query that's being run - Do `echo $sql;die;` to see the SQL that's actually being run.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Comment: sql injection ready ...... go!

Comment: All valid points with injection and newer APIs, Ill look at some newer methods. @Simon _eQ guess you were never new at this huh?, thanks anyway.

Comment: @christian.thomas I would disagree about *this* code being particularly difficult to debug. mySQL is pretty good about throwing errors. Though the answer was already given, **line 16** in this code is actually **line 16 of the SQL statement** and lo and behold, `'$_POST[endTime2]')` had an extra parenthesis at line 16 in the SQL statement. Just a little insight into where the "line 16" bit came from. mySQL doesn't care about the rest of your script, just what you're handing it (the statements).

Comment: @Chris Cirefice ahhh... now that makes sense, I had wondered for a while where the line 16 bit came from!

Comment: Yep, just remember that if you're handing code to another application (eg MySQL, it will only debug its **own** code. As far as I know, that rule applies to pretty much every system that interoperates with another. Particularly, if you separate code line-by-line (more or less how you are), then it helps during debugging as systems (generally) give you a line number to work with in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can see that could cause this is the extra `)` in the following line;

`('$_POST[email]','$_POST[number]','$_POST[ext]','$_POST[startDay]','$_POST[endDay]','$_POST[startTime]','$_POST[endTime]','$_POST[startDay2]','$_POST[endDay2]','$_POST[startTime2]','$_POST[endTime2]'),'$_POST[sine]')";`

Change it to this;

`('$_POST[email]','$_POST[number]','$_POST[ext]','$_POST[startDay]','$_POST[endDay]','$_POST[startTime]','$_POST[endTime]','$_POST[startDay2]','$_POST[endDay2]','$_POST[startTime2]','$_POST[endTime2]','$_POST[sine]')";`

Comment: That was the issue, thanks! For reasons left in the comments Im gonna find a better way of doing this though.

Comment: No problem! Since you're changing your database interaction method may I suggest this wrapper class for the PDO extension; [link]http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/ It is absolutely great! I use it everywhere!

Comment: Perfect place to start, thanks again!