# How to add html table to database and save

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP.I had created the table with the button "save Form".I am unable to save the table data to database.When I click on the "save form" button no action is performing.Please help me.

This is my Form.phtml

```
<div>
    <b> Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>!</b><br>
    <b>Email    :</b> <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>.<br>
    <b>Gender   :</b> <?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?>.<br>
    <b>Birthday :</b>
   <?php
     $day = $_POST['day'];
     $month = $_POST['month'];
     $year = $_POST['year'];
     $date = $day."-".$month."-".$year;
     $myDate = date("d F Y", strtotime($date));
     echo $myDate;
  ?>
    </div>


     <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" id="vaccination-form">
     <div>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">

  <tr>
     <th id= "sno" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class="bg-color" width="5%">S.No</th>
<th id= "vaccine" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class="bg-color center" width="32%">Vaccine</th>     
<th id="decsription" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;">Description</th>
<th id="duedate" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;" class ="bg-color" width="15%">Due Date</th>

   </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <tr>
</table>
 </form>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" style="margin-top: 1cm;"title="<?php echo $this->__('Save Form') ?>" value="submit "class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Save Form')?></span>  </span>    </button>
</div>
```

sendmail.php

```
  <?php
    //due dates
    $myDate=$_POST['myDate'];
    $dueDate=$_POST['dueDate'];
    $rodueDate=$_POST['rodueDate'];
    $didueDate=$_POST['didueDate'];
    $pdueDate=$_POST['pdueDate'];
    $hadueDate=$_POST['hadueDate'];
    $indueDate=$_POST['indueDate'];
    $idueDate=$_POST['idueDate'];
    $rdueDate=$_POST['rdueDate'];
    $vdueDate=$_POST['vdueDate'];
    $tdueDate=$_POST['tdueDate'];
    $hdueDate=$_POST['hdueDate'];
    $mdueDate=$_POST['mdueDate'];

    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $to=$email;
    $subject= "Vaccination Schedule For  ".$name;
    $message= 
    '
</table>';

 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $headers.= "From: someone@example.com" . "\r\n" ;
   if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
   {
            echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully';
   } 
   else
   {
        echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
   }

 ?>
```

Comment: where is `sendmail.php`?

Comment: It is in another file in the same folder.

Comment: show us how you store data?

Comment: I added this but not getting how to insert those values in it <?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
INSERT INTO {$this->getTable('core_vaccination')} (`S.No`, `Vaccine`, `Description`, `Due dates`) VALUES
(NULL, NULL, NOW(), NOW());
");
$installer->endSetup();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the right thing to do , but still think you need to put the submit button  between tags

Comment: If you see the code you can find the submit button in the code.

Comment: Put it between <form> tags

Comment: If I add it in form tags it is redirecting to the sendmail.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Show us your sendmail.php.

Mainly you need to get POST variables into sendmail.php and then create a insert sql statement with data you got from POST variables..

How to do stuff above is totaly up to you, there are many ways, but we cannot tell you since you didnt give us enough info about your system.

Comment: Attached the sendmail.php and it is used for sending mails.

Comment: use your sendmail.php to store sent data to database. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: I need to write a new file for this (or) I need to add this in sendmail.php file.Please suggest me.

Comment: U can use current sendmail.php since you already have all the data you need from form..

Comment: But,If I add this code the mail function is not working.

Comment: Did you even check the link I posted? Your function is wrong, you need to create DB connection first and then build up your sql insert statement and then execute query, so thats at least 7 lines you have to write.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682903/php-script-to-save-post-to-database-and-send-email

Comment: yes,I checked the link that you have posted but  sendmail.php is using for only sending mails